# Selenium Webdriver selecting wrong input in jquery dialog

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jquery-ui-dialog

I am testing a site that has a dialog box with multiple text fields, some with datepickers, some without.

For some reason, when I attempt to locate the inputs by their XPath selenium finds the element, but when it comes time to input data, it send the keys to the top field.  Here is an example of my selenium code:

```
DriverHelper.SendKeysByXpath("//input[@name='registrationStartDate']",CurrentDate);
DriverHelper.SendKeysByXpath("//input[@name='firstStartDate']",CurrentDate);
DriverHelper.SendKeysByXpath("//input[contains(@name,'lastStartDate')]","01/01/2018");
```

FYI, the `DriverHelper` is a class I call to save myself from typing the same selenium calls over and over again.

The XPath names are all unique and as far as I know there shouldn't be any confusion as to which input I'd like to send the keys to.

Has anyone run into similar situations before?

I'm trying to get an example up in jsfiddle but so far I'm unable to replicate the issue there.

Comment: Use Firebug to check your xpaths on the document and make sure they are selecting the element you're looking for at each line.  If there's a difference between the highlighted element in firebug and the element that gets the keys when using the same xpath, you'll need to debug your SendKeysByXpath method.

Comment: It's possible that the page is using JavaScript to force the cursor focus to that element, and after Selenium locates the element, the focus is moved before the keys are sent. IDK.

I'm not familiar with SendKeysByXPath -- is that your own creation? That's a likely culprit. You're XPaths shown here look fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is sending keys to the top element probably because that is the one that he is selecting. 
Try to use this:

```
 List<WebElement> result = webDriver.findElements( by );
```

Debug your code and check how many elements your selector is retrieving.
Try to narrow and improve your search in such a way that you narrow the group os selected elements as possible.

Very personal opinion:
The code is easier to fix and to read if you avoid using xPaths as selectors. I prefer id's and classes whenever its possible.

[Selenium best pratices source](https://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/)

Comment: The confusing thing is that only one element is being retrieved.  Each name is unique and retrieving a list based on name only returns one input field.

I've tried with multiple inputs on this dialog box and the position changes.  That leads me to believe that it's not just defaulting to the top field.